# javax transaction not doing rollback if used with hibernate transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I have a function which is modifying two tables using javax transaction.

```
@Transactional  //javax transaction
  public PayoutTransaction createPayoutTxnAndUpdateDailyPayout(
      PayoutTransaction payoutTransactionModel, List<DailyPayout> dailyPayouts) throws Exception {
    try {
      PayoutTransaction payoutTransaction =
          (PayoutTransaction) payoutTransactionDao.save(payoutTransactionModel);
      updateTransactionId(null, DailyPayoutStatus.PICKED, dailyPayouts);
      return payoutTransaction;
    } catch (Exception exc) {
      LOGGER.error("Error while creating payout transaction with exception: {}",
          CommonUtil.exceptionFormatter(exc));
      throw exc;
    }
  }
```

updateTransactionId function

```
private void updateTransactionId(Long payoutId, DailyPayoutStatus dailyPayoutStatus,
      List<DailyPayout> dailyPayouts) throws Exception {
    List<Long> dailyPayoutIds = new ArrayList<>();
    int retryCount = dailyPayouts.get(0).getRetryCount();
    dailyPayouts.stream().forEach(dailyPayout -> dailyPayoutIds.add(dailyPayout.getId()));
    if (!NullOrEmptyCheckerUtil.isNullOrEmpty(payoutId)) {
      dailyPayoutDao.updatePayoutTransactionId(dailyPayoutIds, payoutId, DailyPayoutStatus.SUCCESS);
    } else {
      dailyPayoutDao.updateDailyPayoutStatus(dailyPayoutIds, DailyPayoutStatus.NOT_PICKED,
          retryCount + 1);
    }
  }
```

And now my save also contains spring trasaction like this

```
@Override
  @Transactional
  public Object save(final Object object) {
    Serializable id = hibernateTemplate.save(object);
    return get(object.getClass(), id);
  }
```

Now if anything breaks in my updateTransactionId function it is not doing the rollback on my save function.
As far my knowledge parent transactional(javax transaction) should override my spring transaction and should rollback my save function data which is not happening.

Comment: This means either you have a wrong transaction setup, in which you don't have transaction or you are using a database/storage engine that doesn't support transactions (like MySQL with MyISAM tables). Also the exception would only occur after the transaction commits so after the outer transaction which basically renders your internal `try/catch` useless.

Comment: This is what i am trying to ask because my outer transactional should override my spring transactional

Comment: As stated either wrong setup or storage engine without tx support.

Comment: I am using mysql

Comment: Check your tables, they are probably using MyISAM as the storage engine. MyISAM doesn't support transactions.

Comment: ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

Comment: Check your table not your mysql configuration. You are using Hibernate if you are using hibernate to manage your schema depending on your chosen dialect it will still create MyISAM tables. Hence that is why I said check your tables.

Comment: It is at my table level not at db level

Comment: Well then your tx setup is simply wrongly configured. However as you haven't included the configuration what is wrong would be a guessing game.

Comment: I got it. This is happening because i have autowired my dao in my service and individual dao has transactional with there method. is there any way by which i can force my dao layer to use my service transactional?

Comment: That is the default behavior... The fact that it isn't acting like that is probably because you have configured your tx infrastructure wrong.